# Retrieve JSON from flash program in IE embed with Autoit

Tags: json, flash, autoit

I am trying to retrieve a JSON  that is sent from the flash program each time I load it.

Using Charles I am able to get the JSON data -  application/json; charset=utf8 POST method - from the website however I would like Autoit to capture the JSON data and paste it into a text file on my desktop.

Basically, whenever I press a button on the flash program, I would like Autoit to parse the JSON data.

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow. Where is your actual technical question? What have you tried so far? Where do you struggle? You can get specific help here, but don't expect a wish-box... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is making a [proxy in pure Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/44138-autoit-proxy-server/#entry774282)

```
#Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#AutoIt3Wrapper_outfile=proxy.exe
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Compression=4
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
TCPStartup()
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIEdit.au3>
#Include <Array.au3>
#Include <File.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Opt("GUIOnEventMode" , 1)
Opt("TrayAutoPause",0)
Opt("TrayMenuMode",3)
Opt("TrayOnEventMode",1)

Global $ini = @ScriptDir & "\config.ini" 
Global $mainarray[30][10]
Global $proxysocket , $proxysocketssl
Global $GUISHOW = 1

$mainarray[0][0] = "Hostport"
$mainarray[0][1] = "Clientsocket"
$mainarray[0][2] = "Hostsocket"
$mainarray[0][3] = "Request"
$mainarray[0][4] = "Hostname"
$mainarray[0][5] = "Timerhandle connection"
$mainarray[0][6] = "Blocked"
$mainarray[0][7] = "State"
$mainarray[0][8] = "connection type"
$mainarray[0][9] = "req count"



Global $gui = GUICreate("ProxyServer v0.2",700,700)
$DEBUG=GUICtrlCreateEdit("" , 5 , 30 , 500 ,670,BitOr($GUI_SS_DEFAULT_EDIT,$ES_READONLY))
GUICtrlSetLimit(-1 , 2000000000000000)
Global $button_debug_clear = GUICtrlCreateButton("Clear",5,5,90,20)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent($button_debug_clear,"_debug_clear")
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Listening IP:",515,40,70,20)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Port HTTP:",515,60,70,20)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Port HTTPS:",515,80,70,20)
Global $input_proxyip =  GUICtrlCreateInput("",590, 40,100,20)
Global $input_proxyport = GUICtrlCreateInput("",590,60,60,20)
Global $input_proxyportssl = GUICtrlCreateInput("",590,80,60,20)
Global $button_proxy_save = GUICtrlCreateButton("Save and Restart",515,140,180,20)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent($button_proxy_save,"_mainsocket_save")

Global $checkbox_debug = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("Debugmode", 515 , 240, 120, 20)
Global $checkbox_debug_save = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("Save Debug to file", 515 , 260, 120, 20)
Global $checkbox_debug_content = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("Show traffic content", 515 , 280, 120, 20)
Global $button_debug_content = GUICtrlCreateButton("Binary to String",515,320,120,19)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent($button_debug_content,"_debug_binary")
Global $button_debug_array = GUICtrlCreateButton("show mainarray",515,340,120,19)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1,"_show_array")


Global $tray_showgui = TrayCreateItem("Show gui")
TrayItemSetOnEvent($tray_showgui,"_gui_show")

GUISetOnEvent($GUI_EVENT_CLOSE,"_quit")
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW,$gui)

_mainsocket_create()

While 1
    $newclientsock  = TCPAccept($proxysocket)
    If $newclientsock <> -1 Then
        _save("] new HTTP clientconnection :" &_SocketToIP($newclientsock) &@CRLF) 
        _clientconnection_to_mainarray($newclientsock,80,"HTTP")
    EndIf
    $newclientsockssl   = TCPAccept($proxysocketssl)
    If $newclientsockssl <> -1 Then
        _save("] new HTTPS clientconnection :" &_SocketToIP($newclientsockssl) &@CRLF) 
        _clientconnection_to_mainarray($newclientsockssl,443,"HTTPS","start")
    EndIf
    ;--Recieving Req from Client
    For $i = 1 To UBound($mainarray) -1
        If $mainarray[$i][1] <> "" Then
            $request = TCPRecv($mainarray[$i][1],100000)
            If @error Then 

                _save("] Client " & $i & " closed connection after " & Floor(TimerDiff($mainarray[$i][5])) & " ms" & @CRLF)
                _mainarray_deleteclient($i)
            EndIf

            If $request <> "" Then
                _save("] Client " & $i & " requested" & @CRLF  & @CRLF & $request & @CRLF)
                $mainarray[$i][9] += 1 
                $mainarray[$i][3] = $request
                If GUICtrlRead($checkbox_debug_content) = 1 Then _save($request & @CRLF)
            EndIf   
        EndIf
    Next

    ;--connecting and sending Req to Host
    For $i = 1 To UBound($mainarray) -1
        If $mainarray[$i][3] <> "" Then
            If $mainarray[$i][2] = "" Then
                $forward = _Get_Address($mainarray[$i][3])
                _save("]" & $i &" Got Host Address : " & $forward  & @CRLF)         
                $mainarray[$i][6] = 0
                $mainarray[$i][4] = $forward
                If $forward = "0" Then
                    _Send_Response($mainarray[$i][1],400)
                    _save("]" & $i &" Host is 0 , Error 400" & @CRLF)
                Else
                        $serverip   = TCPNameToIP($forward)
                        $serversock = TCPConnect($serverip,$mainarray[$i][0])
                        If $serversock <> -1 Then
                            _save("]" & $i &" Connected to Host: " & $forward & @CRLF)
                            $mainarray[$i][2] = $serversock

                        Else
                            _save("]" & $i &" Not Connected to Host: " & $forward & @CRLF)
                            _Send_Response($mainarray[$i][1],400)
                            _mainarray_deleteclient($i)
                        EndIf
                EndIf   
            Else
                $forward = _Get_Address($mainarray[$i][3])
                If $forward <> $mainarray[$i][4] Then
                    _save("]" & $i &" Host Address changed from: " & $mainarray[$i][4] & " to: " & $forward & @CRLF)
                    $mainarray[$i][4] = $forward
                    TCPCloseSocket($mainarray[$i][2])
                    $mainarray[$i][2] = ""
                EndIf
            EndIf
            If $mainarray[$i][2] <> "" Then
                $prevlen = StringLen($mainarray[$i][3])
                $mainarray[$i][3] = _request_modify($mainarray[$i][3],$mainarray[$i][4])
                If $mainarray[$i][7] = "" Then 
                    ;$mainarray[$i][3] = _request_modify($mainarray[$i][3],$mainarray[$i][4])
                    TCPSend($mainarray[$i][2] , $mainarray[$i][3])
                        If Not @error Then
                            _save("]" & $i &" Sending HTTP to Host " & $mainarray[$i][4] & " successfull prevlen:" & $prevlen & " now:" & StringLen($mainarray[$i][3]) & @CRLF)
                            $mainarray[$i][3] = ""
                        Else
                            _save("]" & $i &" Error Sending HTTP to Host " & @CRLF)
                        EndIf
                EndIf
            EndIf
        EndIf
    Next
    ;--Waiting for Response from Host and Sending to client
    For $i = 1 To UBound($mainarray) -1
        If $mainarray[$i][2] <> "" Then
            $serverresponse     = TCPRecv($mainarray[$i][2],400000,1)   
            If @error Then 
                _mainarray_hostkillclient($i)
            EndIf
            If $serverresponse <> Binary("") Then
                If $mainarray[$i][6] = 0 Then 
                    _save("]" & $i &" Got Host response" & @CRLF)
                    If  $mainarray[$i][1] <> "" And $mainarray[$i][7] = "" Then
                        TCPSend($mainarray[$i][1],$serverresponse)
                        If Not @error Then
                            _save("]" & $i &" Sent data to Client " & @CRLF)

                            If GUICtrlRead($checkbox_debug_content) = 1 Then _save(BinaryToString($serverresponse) & @CRLF)
                        EndIf       
                    EndIf   
                ElseIf $mainarray[$i][6] = 1 Then 
                    TCPSend($mainarray[$i][1],"HTTP/1.1 " & "403")
                    _mainarray_hostkillclient($i)
                EndIf
            EndIf
        EndIf
    Next    
    ;---only for HTTPS
    For $i = 1 To UBound($mainarray) -1
        If $mainarray[$i][1] <> "" And $mainarray[$i][3] <> "" And $mainarray[$i][8] = "HTTPS" And $mainarray[$i][7] = "start" Then
            _Send_Response($mainarray[$i][1],200) ;,$data="")
            $mainarray[$i][3] = ""
            $mainarray[$i][7] = ""
        EndIf
    Next

WEnd    

Func _show_array()
    _ArrayDisplay($mainarray)
EndFunc

Func _mainsocket_save()
    IniWrite($ini,"SYSTEM","PROXYPORT",GUICtrlRead($input_proxyport))
    IniWrite($ini,"SYSTEM","PROXYIP",GUICtrlRead($input_proxyip))
    IniWrite($ini,"SYSTEM","PROXYPORTSSL",GUICtrlRead($input_proxyportssl))
    _mainsocket_create()
EndFunc

Func _mainsocket_create()
    TCPShutdown()
    TCPStartup()
    $IP = IniRead($ini,"SYSTEM","PROXYIP","127.0.0.1")
    $PORT = IniRead($ini,"SYSTEM","PROXYPORT","8080")
    $PORTSSL = IniRead($ini,"SYSTEM","PROXYPORTSSL","8043")
    GUICtrlSetData($input_proxyip, $IP)
    GUICtrlSetData($input_proxyport,$PORT)
    GUICtrlSetData($input_proxyportssl,$PORTSSL)
    $proxysocket        = TCPListen($IP,$PORT)
    If @error Then 
        _GUICtrlEdit_AppendText($DEBUG , "] Error HTTP Proxy couldn't bind socket on IP :" & $IP & " Port :" & $PORT & @CRLF)
    Else
        _GUICtrlEdit_AppendText($DEBUG , "] HTTP Proxy listening on IP :" & $IP & " Port :" & $PORT & @CRLF)
    EndIf   
    $proxysocketssl     = TCPListen($IP,$PORTSSL)
    If @error Then 
        _GUICtrlEdit_AppendText($DEBUG , "] Error HTTPS Proxy couldn't bind socket on IP :" & $IP & " Port :" & $PORTSSL & @CRLF)
    Else
        _GUICtrlEdit_AppendText($DEBUG , "] HTTPS Proxy listening on IP :" & $IP & " Port :" & $PORTSSL & @CRLF)
    EndIf       
EndFunc


Func _Get_Address($text)
    If IsBinary($text) Then 
        $text = BinaryToString($text)
    EndIf
        $serversock=StringSplit($text , @CRLF,1)
        For $i=1 To $serversock[0]
            If StringLeft($serversock[$i],6)="Host: " Then
                Return StringTrimLeft($serversock[$i],6)
            EndIf
        Next
    Return 0        
EndFunc

Func _clientconnection_to_mainarray($sock,$port = 80,$type = "HTTP",$state = "")
    For $i = 1 To UBound($mainarray) -1
        If $mainarray[$i][1] = "" And $mainarray[$i][2] = "" Then
            $mainarray[$i][1] = $sock
            $mainarray[$i][0] = $port
            $mainarray[$i][5] = TimerInit()
            $mainarray[$i][7] = $state
            $mainarray[$i][8] = $type
            _save("] Added new client to mainarray , pos: " & $i & @CRLF)
            If $i + 5 > UBound($mainarray) Then ReDim $mainarray[UBound($mainarray)+5][10]
            Return
        EndIf   
    Next
EndFunc

Func _mainarray_deleteclient($line)
    TCPCloseSocket($mainarray[$line][1])
    $mainarray[$line][0] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][1] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][3] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][4] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][5] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][6] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][7] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][8] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][9] = ""
    If $mainarray[$line][2]<> "" Then
        TCPCloseSocket($mainarray[$line][2])
        $mainarray[$line][2] = ""
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _mainarray_hostkillclient($line)
    _save("]" & $line &" Connection Closed by Host after " & Floor(TimerDiff($mainarray[$line][5])) & " ms" & @CRLF)
    $mainarray[$line][2] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][4] = ""
    $mainarray[$line][5] = ""
    If $mainarray[$line][1]<> "" Then
        TCPCloseSocket($mainarray[$line][1])
        _mainarray_deleteclient($line)
    EndIf   
EndFunc

Func _Send_Response($browsersock,$code,$data="")
    If $data="" Then
        $data=@CRLF & @CRLF 
    Else
        $data=@CRLF & $data & @CRLF & @CRLF 
    EndIf
    TCPSend($browsersock , "HTTP/1.0 " & $code & " Message" & $data)
EndFunc


Func _quit()
    TCPShutdown()
    Exit
EndFunc

Func _gui_show()
    If $GUISHOW = 0 Then
        Local $pw = InputBox("Enter Password","Enter Password","","*",150,130)
        If Not @error Then
            If $pw = "1234" Then 
                GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
                $GUISHOW = 1
                Return
            EndIf   
        EndIf
    ElseIf $GUISHOW = 1 Then
        GUISetState(@SW_HIDE)
        $GUISHOW = 0
        Return      
    EndIf
EndFunc 

Func _save($text)
    If GUICtrlRead($checkbox_debug_save) = 1 Then
        $file = FileOpen(@ScriptDir & "\log\" & @Year & @MON & @MDAY & "-log.txt",9)
        FileWrite ($file,$text)
        FileClose($file)
    Endif
    If GUICtrlRead($checkbox_debug) = 1 Then _GUICtrlEdit_AppendText($DEBUG , $text)
Endfunc

Func _SocketToIP($SHOCKET)
    Local $sockaddr, $aRet
    $sockaddr = DllStructCreate("short;ushort;uint;char[8]")
    $aRet = DllCall("Ws2_32.dll", "int", "getpeername", "int", $SHOCKET, _
            "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($sockaddr), "int*", DllStructGetSize($sockaddr))
    If Not @error And $aRet[0] = 0 Then
        $aRet = DllCall("Ws2_32.dll", "str", "inet_ntoa", "int", DllStructGetData($sockaddr, 3))
        If Not @error Then $aRet = $aRet[0]
    Else
        $aRet = 0
    EndIf
    $sockaddr = 0
    Return $aRet
EndFunc   ;==>SocketToIP

Func _debug_binary()
    Local $aSel = _GUICtrlEdit_GetSel($DEBUG)
    Local $text = StringMid(GUICtrlRead($DEBUG),$aSel[0]+1,$aSel[1]-$aSel[0])
    If $text <> "" Then 

    Else    
        $text = InputBox("Binary to String","Enter Binary Data") 

    EndIf
    If StringLower(StringLeft($text,2)) <> "0x" Then $text = "0x" & $text
    $tempfile = FileOpen(@ScriptDir & "\temp.txt",2)
    FileWrite($tempfile,BinaryToString($text))
    FileClose($tempfile)
    ShellExecute(@ScriptDir & "\temp.txt")
EndFunc 

Func _debug_clear()
    GUICtrlSetData($DEBUG,"")
EndFunc 

Func _request_modify($req,$host)
Local $encoding = "Accept-Encoding: identity" ;deflate, gzip, compress, 
Local $reqsplit
Local $modified_method = 0 , $modified_connection = 0 , $modified_encoding = 0
    If $req <> "" And Not IsBinary($req) Then
        $reqsplit = StringSplit($req,@CRLF,1)       
        If IsArray($reqsplit) Then
            For $i = 1 to $reqsplit[0] - 1
                _save("] modifying :" & $i & " " & $reqsplit[$i])
                If StringLeft($reqsplit[$i],3) = "GET" Or StringLeft($reqsplit[$i],4) = "POST" Or StringLeft($reqsplit[$i],7) = "CONNECT" And $modified_method = 0 Then
                        $reqsplit[$i] = StringReplace($reqsplit[$i],$host,"")
                        $reqsplit[$i] = StringReplace($reqsplit[$i],"http://","")
                        $reqsplit[$i] = StringReplace($reqsplit[$i],":443","")
                        $modified_method = 1
                EndIf 
                If StringInStr(Stringlower($reqsplit[$i]),"proxy-connection: keep-alive") And $modified_connection = 0 Then 
                    $reqsplit[$i] = "Connection: keep-alive"
                    $modified_connection = 1
                EndIf   
                If StringInStr(Stringlower($reqsplit[$i]),"accept-encoding") And $modified_encoding = 0 Then 
                    $reqsplit[$i] = $encoding
                    $modified_encoding = 1
                EndIf   
                _save(" -> to :" & $reqsplit[$i] & @CRLF)
            Next    
            $req = _ArrayToString($reqsplit, @CRLF , 1 , Ubound($reqsplit)-1)
        EndIf
        If GUICtrlRead($checkbox_debug_content) = 1 Then
            _save("] Request modified to:" & @CRLF)
            _save($req &@CRLF)
        EndIf
    EndIf
    Return $req
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [WinPcap Autoit3 UDF](http://opensource.grisambre.net/pcapau3/)

Look at the Example(3): Saving http traffic to a pcap file for 10s...